# Google's sign-in quickstart app is crashing

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

So I'm trying to run google's quickstart app as a sample app for their sign-in API. The app does run but crashes after I choose a google account.

This is what my logcat says:

```
09-19 11:04:27.821  21328-21328/com.google.samples.quickstart.signin E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.samples.quickstart.signin, PID: 21328
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion: i
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.unknownFormatConversionException(Formatter.java:1399)
        at java.util.Formatter$FormatToken.checkFlags(Formatter.java:1336)
        at java.util.Formatter.transform(Formatter.java:1442)
        at java.util.Formatter.doFormat(Formatter.java:1081)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1042)
        at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:1011)
        at java.lang.String.format(String.java:1999)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:1542)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:376)
        at com.google.samples.quickstart.signin.MainActivity.showErrorDialog(MainActivity.java:237)
        at com.google.samples.quickstart.signin.MainActivity.onConnectionFailed(MainActivity.java:212)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk.zzj(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzf(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzc(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg$zza$1.zznn(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi$zzb.zzf(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzi$zza.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.google.samples.quickstart.signin;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;


/**
 * Minimal activity demonstrating basic Google Sign-In.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    /* RequestCode for resolutions involving sign-in */
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    /* Keys for persisting instance variables in savedInstanceState */
    private static final String KEY_IS_RESOLVING = "is_resolving";
    private static final String KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE = "should_resolve";

    /* Client for accessing Google APIs */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /* View to display current status (signed-in, signed-out, disconnected, etc) */
    private TextView mStatus;

    /* Is there a ConnectionResult resolution in progress? */
    private boolean mIsResolving = false;

    /* Should we automatically resolve ConnectionResults when possible? */
    private boolean mShouldResolve = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Restore from saved instance state
        // [START restore_saved_instance_state]
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsResolving = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING);
            mShouldResolve = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE);
        }
        // [END restore_saved_instance_state]

        // Set up button click listeners
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.disconnect_button).setOnClickListener(this);

        // Large sign-in
        ((SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button)).setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);

        // Start with sign-in button disabled until sign-in either succeeds or fails
        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setEnabled(false);

        // Set up view instances
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        // [START create_google_api_client]
        // Build GoogleApiClient with access to basic profile
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.PROFILE))
                .build();
        // [END create_google_api_client]
    }

    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            // Show signed-in user's name
            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (currentPerson != null) {
                String name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_fmt, name));
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, getString(R.string.error_null_person));
                mStatus.setText(getString(R.string.signed_in_err));
            }

            // Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Show signed-out message
            mStatus.setText(R.string.signed_out);

            // Set button visibility
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setEnabled(true);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.sign_out_and_disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    // [START on_start_on_stop]
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    // [END on_start_on_stop]

    // [START on_save_instance_state]
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IS_RESOLVING, mIsResolving);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_SHOULD_RESOLVE, mShouldResolve);
    }
    // [END on_save_instance_state]

    // [START on_activity_result]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            // If the error resolution was not successful we should not resolve further errors.
            if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mShouldResolve = false;
            }

            mIsResolving = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    // [END on_activity_result]

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        // onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the device, that the selected
        // account has granted any requested permissions to our app and that we were able to
        // establish a service connection to Google Play services.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected:" + bundle);

        // Show the signed-in UI
        updateUI(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost. The GoogleApiClient will automatically
        // attempt to re-connect. Any UI elements that depend on connection to Google APIs should
        // be hidden or disabled until onConnected is called again.
        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionSuspended:" + i);
    }

    // [START on_connection_failed]
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Could not connect to Google Play Services.  The user needs to select an account,
        // grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in. Refer to the javadoc for
        // ConnectionResult to see possible error codes.
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed:" + connectionResult);

        if (!mIsResolving && mShouldResolve) {
            if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIsResolving = true;
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not resolve ConnectionResult.", e);
                    mIsResolving = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else {
                // Could not resolve the connection result, show the user an
                // error dialog.
                showErrorDialog(connectionResult);
            }
        } else {
            // Show the signed-out UI
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }
    // [END on_connection_failed]

    private void showErrorDialog(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)) {
            // Show the default Google Play services error dialog which may still start an intent
            // on our behalf if the user can resolve the issue.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            mShouldResolve = false;
                            updateUI(false);
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else {
            // No default Google Play Services error, display a message to the user.
            String errorString = getString(R.string.play_services_error_fmt, errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(this, errorString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mShouldResolve = false;
            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_in_button:
                // User clicked the sign-in button, so begin the sign-in process and automatically
                // attempt to resolve any errors that occur.
                mStatus.setText(R.string.signing_in);
                // [START sign_in_clicked]
                mShouldResolve = true;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                // [END sign_in_clicked]
                break;
            case R.id.sign_out_button:
                // Clear the default account so that GoogleApiClient will not automatically
                // connect in the future.
                // [START sign_out_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                // [END sign_out_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;
            case R.id.disconnect_button:
                // Revoke all granted permissions and clear the default account.  The user will have
                // to pass the consent screen to sign in again.
                // [START disconnect_clicked]
                if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                // [END disconnect_clicked]
                updateUI(false);
                break;

        }
    }
}
```

Does someone know how to fix this????

UPDATE: This is my strings.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Sign-In Quickstart</string>
    <string name="title_text">Google Sign-In\nQuickstart</string>

    <!-- Sign-in status messages -->
    <string name="signed_in_fmt">Signed in as: %s</string>
    <string name="signing_in">Signing in…</string>
    <string name="signed_out">Signed out</string>
    <string name="signed_in_err">"Error: please check logs."</string>
    <string name="error_null_person">
        Error: Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson returned null. Ensure that the Google+ API is
        enabled for your project, you have a properly configured google-services.json file
        and that your device has an internet connection.
    </string>

    <!-- Google Play Services error for Toast -->
    <string name="play_services_error_fmt">Google Play Services Error: %i</string>

    <!-- Button labels -->
    <string name="sign_out">Sign Out</string>
    <string name="disconnect">Disconnect</string>

    <!-- Content Description for images -->
    <string name="desc_google_icon">Google Logo</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: post your strings.xml.

Comment: Also can you point which line is `MainActivity.java:237)`. You can try to toast error code like.Toast.makeText(this,"Error code is"+ error_code, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();